# didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead Stripe Checkout

Tags: django

I have a problem because I can not make Stripe work with my django project. As in title I get an error. It is really rough to integrate Django with the Stripe.

```
ValueError at /create_checkout_session
The view shop.views.create_checkout_session didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_checkout_session
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view shop.views.create_checkout_session didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

views.py

```
def create_checkout_session(request):
    MY_DOMAIN = 'localhost:8000'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(order_user=request.user)
            stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('stripeAPI')
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price': 'price_1JUTtYIXuOafNhy8tmWVwgjG',
                        'quantity': 1,
                    },
                ],
                payment_method_types=[
                'card',
                'p24',
                ],
                mode='payment',
                success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success-page'))+ '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url= request.build_absolute_url(reverse('cancel-page')),
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
        return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

Comment: for a GET request, your view does not return anything.

Comment: You need to return a response in GET method if you are trying to access your view in GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `GET` method for GET requests. As you are sending a GET request to your server.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```